# Why does "export" not work in docker exec?

Tags: docker

I have exported variables in `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh` and `~/.bashrc`. They are available in the environment when I run `docker exec -i CONT_ID /bin/bash`. But when I run another command, they are not available in command's environment. It's right, so I try to do this:

```
docker exec -i "$MYCONTNAME" /bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/custom.sh; echo $MYVAR"
```

It does not work. I try even:

```
docker exec -i "$MYCONTNAME" /bin/bash -c "export Y=123; echo Y=$Y"
docker exec -i "$MYCONTNAME" /bin/bash -c "export Y=123 && echo Y=$Y"
```

but they don't work either. I can add `-e VARi=VALi` but they are located in shell script file with as `export`ing variables, so is it any way to get working way with `/bin/bash` (`source /etc/profile.d/custom.sh`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$MYVAR` in the command

```
docker exec -i "$MYCONTNAME" /bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/custom.sh; echo $MYVAR"
```

will be expanded before `/bin/bash -c` is executed (since it's in double quotes).

Instead, use single quotes:

```
docker exec -i "$MYCONTNAME" /bin/bash -c 'source /etc/profile.d/custom.sh; echo $MYVAR'
```

Alternatively (untested),

```
docker exec -i "$MYCONTNAME" /usr/bin/env BASH_ENV=/etc/profile.d/custom.sh /bin/bash -c 'echo $MYVAR'
```

If `BASH_ENV` is set when a non-interactive shell is started (with e.g. `bash -c`), the file that the variable points to will be sourced before the shell runs its commands.

Comment: I don't follow, will the `echo` command be an equivalent to `export`?

Comment: @knocte No. The user's issue is that the variable is expanded even before the `docker` command is executed, due to the use of double-quotes. I'm suggesting using single quotes to stop the invoking shell from expanding the variable in the command that the user wants to run in the container. The `echo` command is the command that the user wants to execute in the container and I say nothing about this. I'm assuming that `MYVAR` is a variable set in the file `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh` that the user sources.  Whether it is exported or not is unimportant to this question.

Comment: ah thanks my bad